# How can I generate a sample Rails app with Opal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, opalrb

I'm following the guide at http://opalrb.org/docs/rails/ .  The first step goes fine:

```
rails new MyHappyApp --javascript=opal
```

But when I try to actually generate a scaffold...

```
rails g scaffold Persion name age:int
/home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails32/gems/opal-sprockets-0.0.1/lib/opal/sprockets/server.rb:81: warning: already initialized constant Opal::Server::Index::SOURCE
/home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails32/gems/opal-0.3.44/lib/opal/server.rb:90: warning: previous definition of SOURCE was here
    SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
    This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
    provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
    cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
    future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

    Called from: /home/jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails32/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20140613172929_create_persions.rb
  create    app/models/persion.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/unit/persion_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/persions.yml
   route  resources :persions
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  create    app/controllers/persions_controller.rb
  invoke    erb
  create      app/views/persions
  create      app/views/persions/index.html.erb
  create      app/views/persions/edit.html.erb
  create      app/views/persions/show.html.erb
  create      app/views/persions/new.html.erb
  create      app/views/persions/_form.html.erb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/functional/persions_controller_test.rb
  invoke    helper
  create      app/helpers/persions_helper.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  create        test/unit/helpers/persions_helper_test.rb
  invoke  assets
   error    opal [not found]
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/persions.css.scss
  invoke  scss
  create    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting the 'error    opal [not found]' line?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this and was able to replicate the error.

As far as I can tell, `opal-rails` does not actually provide any assets generators. Following Rails conventions, there should be an `assets_generator.rb` file at or around `opal-rails/lib/rails/generators/opal/assets`, but there is no such file in the source code.

You could add an assets generator to the project yourself (see https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails/blob/master/lib/rails/generators/coffee/assets/assets_generator.rb and associated files for an example of what an assets generator would look like).

Another alternative would be to just set `config.app_generators.javascript_engine = :js` in your `application.rb` file, and then just rename it appropriately (e.g., to `persons.js.rb`).

Comment: Just pushed a simple view generator in opal-rails master: https://github.com/opal/opal-rails/commit/88c26bfc1ca9c3c84c3cf2286953c5e9f437aee6